# Rename a field to resolve data in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am working on an API built with Apollo Server (Node.js). I use a Rest API as a source and some of the responses have keys that contain dashes. The problem is GraphQL does not allow dashes in the field names. I don't have control over the source, so I can't rename the fields there.

Example REST API response:

```
{
   "content": {
       "en-CA": {
            "title": "Die Hard"
            ...
       }
   }
}
```

My schema:

```
type Content {
    title: String
}
type Movie {
   content: {
      "en-CA": Content
   }
}
```

But the above example does not work, as it contains a dash.

Is there a way to rename the field to match the source field name and resolve the data?

Comment: You just need to add a custom resolver for the field in question. See the linked dupe for details.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danstarns/e62eadcbe1afac7e744e43e6f23b6ed5